# Is repo forall silent about its output

Tags: git-lfs, repo

After initializeing with `repo init` and synchronizing it with `repo sync` I am doing

```
repo forall -j 4 -p -c 'git lfs pull'
```

I have two questions

1. What is `-j 4` for? I cannot find documentation on this
2. When I execute the command, there is absolutely no output. I tried adding -v and the same. Is repo forall silent about its output?

Comment: I'm guessing the -j 4 is for the amount of job-threads; See the documentation for repo sync, using $ repo help sync

Answer (score 0):

`-j 4` is number of jobs to run in parallel, you can get help from `repo forall --help`

`repo forall` is not silent and you should have got the output. For debugging the issue, you can set `REPO_TRACE=1` environment variable and run the command again to understand what is the issue.